# Set Default Table Size to 1x1

Tags: onenote

I need to set the default table size 2 one row, and one column, but I cannot find any solution. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. Please bear in mind that this site is not a help desk, service desk, customer service. It also doesn't work as other sites do. The site [tour] literally says, "Get answers to practical, detailed questions" and follows, saying: "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do."